# Set bubble transparency in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

Is there a way to influence the transparency of the bubbles in Highcharts bubble charts?
I was looking for a configuration comparable to area fillColor, but didn't find one.

I tried using  rgba colors for the series, like so:

```
       series: [{
        color: "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)",
        data: [
```

but that only made the border semi transparent.

Edit: 
I just tried to use marker fillColor:

```
series: [{
        color: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
        marker: {
            fillColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.1)"
        },
```

but that doesn't influence the transparency

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use fillOpacity parameter,

```
marker: {
          fillOpacity:0.3
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8JcL/116/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Precisely what I needed! HighCharts should add this to API reference.

Comment: that it doesn't use the transparency portion of an RGBA color seems like a bug...is that the case?

Comment: Agreed with Koos, there is no mention of it still in the API docs.

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of the properties that are only used on series level and can't be set per point.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be adding a CSS property.

```
.highcharts-point {
    fill-opacity: 0.8;
  }
```

But this will be applied to all the bubbles.