# How do I change an individual bubble's color and opacity in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a HighCharts BubbleChart and am trying to make adjustment to the color and opacity of an individual bubble. I seem to be able to adjust the color but the opacity stays fixed at 0.5 (When I view the Bubble's properties in the browser's DOM Inspector). This seems to be some sort of HighCharts default (for the whole series?), how do I modify it on an individual basis?

Below is a minimal HighCharts example showing the issue.

Also, the same code on Plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/Wl7HhVgwOffN1CL3DxtC

If you view the yellow bubble in the DOM Inspector you'll see it has an opacity of 0.5 although in the code it is clearly set to 1.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Bubbles'
    },

    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        bubble: {
            minSize: 3,
            maxSize: 50
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
          {x:9,y:81,z:63},
          {x:98,y:5,z:89,color:"rgba(255,255,0,1)"},
          {x:51,y:50,z:73}
        ],
    }]

    });
});
```

Comment: Is this what you are after?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896821/set-bubble-transparency-in-highcharts

Comment: @mdc No. As I said, I only want to change an individual bubble and that appears to address the whole series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only when `fillOpacity` is set to 1 you can change the opacity of a color using fillColor for set it.

Maybe you want to read this: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4278

Edit for add this example:

```
{ x:51,
  y:50,
  z:73,
  color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
  marker: {
    fillColor:0,
    fillOpacity:1
  }
}
```

--- Edit ---

After a little discusion and review of the library this appear to be the only trick to made this work has expected:

https://plnkr.co/edit/MvAC94ovCwvPQCe3tZo3?p=preview

Extract:

```
series: [{
            data: [
              {x:9,y:81,z:63},
              { x:98,
                y:5,
                z:89
              },
              { x:51,
                y:50,
                z:73,
                color: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgba(255,255,0,0.1)'],
                        [1, 'rgba(255,255,0,0.1)']
                    ]
                }
              }
            ],
        }]
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything for me. If I add the marker as you've shown it adds a black marker with opacity 1 and the effect I want is for it to be a yellow circle with an opacity of 0.5.

Comment: check this bro https://plnkr.co/edit/OnPWYBazRfBE99dsI9Fs?p=preview here i apply what i said before. Pay attention to the line "colors" that define what colors you are able to pick on your individual series.

Comment: In the inspector both of your bubbles have an opacity of 0.5, as I said before this seems to be a global default and I think you're confusing yourself. When I change the opacity of the circle at x:51, y:50 the opacity doesn't change, it stays at 0.5. Do you see what I mean? Suppose, in your example, you wanted the circle at x:51, y:50 to be yellow with an opacity of 1, and only that circle, how would you do that?

Comment: Bro sorry about the mistake, spelling and faster explaination, the truth is i dont know why cant change from 0 or 1 the opacity ... this work for me in the past. But you can make this work using a gradient, i dont know why but this aproach override the apparent global Opacity, check this, if you want functionality this will help you: https://plnkr.co/edit/MvAC94ovCwvPQCe3tZo3?p=preview

Comment: if you post your last comment (the one with the gradient trick) I'll accept it as an answer. As of now it seems to be the only workable solution to this in HighCharts.

Comment: I edited this answer and add an extract of the aprox "solution"

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
series: [{
    data: [
      {x:9,y:81,z:63},
      {x:98,y:5,z:89, color: 'yellow'},
      {x:51,y:50,z:73}
    ],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3mtmmfzx/52/

Edit:
Would 100% opacity and 50% (the default) be enough to switch between?

If so you could just switch between `'yellow'` and `'rgb(255,255,0)'`

Comment: That definitely has the effect of changing the yellow to be opacity 1, a different color and opacity than the other circles in the series. However, if I want to change the opacity of the yellow to something other than 1 (or 0.5) it seems stuck at 1 now.